# Remote Desktop Service Deployment on Windows Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

I tried to setup Remote Desktop Service Deployment in high availability mode over Windows Server 2012 following [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2012/06/27/rd-connection-broker-high-availability-in-windows-server-2012.aspx).

Everything works fine. The only issue is with Set-RDConnectionBrokerHighAvailability command. In this command database connection string is working with the IP of database but not with the FQDN of database server. It showed me error that database server is not reachable when I used FQDN. I need that to be work with FQDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to solve my problem but i am able to find a way around. i found another cmdlets **Set-RDDatabaseConnectionString**. Set-RDDatabaseConnectionString cmdlet configures database connection settings for the SQL Server database used in high availability environments with multiple Remote Desktop Connection Broker (RD Connection Broker) servers. I used it with FQDN and it works fine.

Thanks